# Problem with working with Multipart form data Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipartform-data, multipart, retrofit2.6

I know it is not wise to use multipart for simple text authentication. but I need to use it with api provided to me.
I tried all the methods possible.

It's working fine with postman
but not with retrofit 2

[request type details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS3Bn.png)

[request type details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6tqP.png)

code used
tried

```
    //RequestBody requestNameRq = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),serviceNameValue);
    //RequestBody requestAmountRq = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),serviceAmountValue.toString());

/* Create Request Body */
//MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
//        .addFormDataPart("service",serviceNameValue)
//        .addFormDataPart("amount", String.valueOf(serviceAmountValue));


//RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
//        .addFormDataPart("service",serviceNameValue)
//        .addFormDataPart("amount",serviceAmountValue.toString()).build();

//MultipartBody.Part  multipartRequestBody = MultipartBody.Part
//        .createFormData("service",serviceNameValue)
//        .createFormData("amount",serviceAmountValue.toString());



//MultipartBody multipartBody = builder.build();
```

Code for Apiservice

```
       @POST("services")
        Call<AddServiceResponse> addService(@Header("Authorization") String authToken,
                                            //@Body MultipartBody body);
                                            @Part("service") RequestBody service,
                                            @Part("amount") RequestBody amount);
                                            //@Part("service") String service,
                                            //@Part("amount") String password);
                                            //@Part("service") RequestBody service,
                                            //@Part("amount") RequestBody amount);
}
```

Comment: Have you annotated your api method with [`@Multipart`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Multipart.html) annotation?

Comment: yes I used @Multipart

Comment: Just a suggestion: Do you know in PostMan there is an option `Code` in right side corner and when you click it, you can find code to request that API in any specific programming language. Just use it and try to compare your request code. It helps in most of the cases to figure things out.

Comment: @RakshithMR 1. What do you mean *is not working with retrofit*: maybe you have error stack or at least status code or something else? please add this info to your question 2. also add code where you prepare parameters and call `addService` method please

Comment: @art  Other requests are working fine. I am getting a html page as a response If I request Json Type It's showing unauthorised, in error body, But It's working fine with postman.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to add

```
@Multipart
```

before

```
@POST("services")
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your ApiService class

```
@Multipart
@POST("services")
        Call<AddServiceResponse> addService(
                                       @Header("Authorization") String authToken,
                                       @Part("service") MultipartBody.Part service,
                                       @Part("amount") MultipartBody.Part amount);
```

Then create MultipartBody

```
MultipartBody.Part serviceBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("service", "Somethin2");
MultipartBody.Part amountBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("amount", "2344");
```

Then call

```
apiService.addService(serviceBody, amountBody);
```

Comment: I am not supposed to use @Part("name") so I am using "@Part MultipartBody.part service" format, also corrected apiservice(authtoken,serviceBody,amountBody) not working